# Set format of cells produced by LoadFromCollection (epplus) using data annotation

Tags: data-annotations, epplus, excelpackage

I am using eeplus to create an excel spreadsheet, like this

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
  var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Customers");
  ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(customers, PrintHeaders: true);

  var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  pck.SaveAs(ms);

  ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

The customer class has properties like

```
[DisplayName("Customer creation date")]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

`DisplayName` seems to get honored, so the topmost line will read `Customer creation date` but the cell contents show up as `43257,41667`.

What I would really like to have is cells that has the format `2018-04-05`.

Can I do that will data annotations? I tried both

```
[DisplayName("Customer creation date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

and

```
[DisplayName("Customer creation date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

but the cell contents remains the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, EPPlus doesnot format your data according to data annotations.
It formats date as integers, so you should specify the column you wish to format as

```
ws.Column(colPosition+1).Style.Number.Format="yyyy-mm-dd";
```

You can find details here:
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formatting-and-styling

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/139569/ensuring-specific-columns-in-an-excelworksheet-format-as-shortdate

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus always changed column name while updating into excel based upon DisplayName Attribute else if there is no DisplayName Attribute is set, then it will Find `"_"` (underscore) character & replace it with `" "` (Space) Character in the column name, Due to which we cannot easily find PropertyInfo with help of column name to format the column as per our need.

**Here is the simple & quickest solution to format column based upon indexing the PropertyInfo**

```
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
{
    Type t = props[i].PropertyType;
    if (t == typeof(DateTime) || t == typeof(DateTime?))
        ws.Column(i + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    else if (t == typeof(TimeSpan) || t == typeof(TimeSpan?))
        ws.Column(i + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
}
```

**I have another solution if you need to format columns based upon column names.**

```
void ApplyDateTimeFormatting<T>(ExcelWorksheet ws, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    if (data.Count() == 0) 
        return;
    Type type = data.First().GetType();
    for (int c = 1; c <= toColumns; c++)
    {
        string column = ws.Cells[1, c].Text;
        var t = type.GetPropertyWithDisplayName<T>(column).PropertyType;
        if (t == typeof(DateTime) || t == typeof(DateTime?))
            ws.Column(c).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        else if (t == typeof(TimeSpan) || t == typeof(TimeSpan?))                
            ws.Column(c).Style.Numberformat.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
    }
}

PropertyInfo GetPropertyFromDisplayName(Type type, string DisplayName)
{
    MemberInfo[] members = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var member in members)
    {
        DisplayNameAttribute displayNameAttribute = member
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), inherit: false)
            .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayNameAttribute;
        string text = ((displayNameAttribute == null) ? member.Name.Replace('_', ' ') :
            displayNameAttribute.DisplayName);
        if (text == DisplayName)
            return type.GetProperty(member.Name);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows, so I just load the model and change as per my model if it is `int` or `datetime`

```
var li = typeof(Model).GetProperties().ToArray();
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
var i = 0;
foreach (var c in li)
{
  i++;
  if(c.PropertyType.Name == typeof(DateTime).Name || c.PropertyType.Name == typeof(DateTime?).Name)
                            workSheet.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern; ;
    
 if (c.PropertyType.Name == typeof(int).Name || c.PropertyType.Name == typeof(int?).Name)
                            workSheet.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";                    
}

}
```